Django: Unable to Retrieve Phone Number from User's Latest CartOrder in Chatbot View
Problem:
I'm building a chatbot using Django and I'm having trouble getting the phone number from my CartOrder model. I have a view called log_customer_query that's supposed to return the phone number of the user's latest order, but it's not working.
Code:
Here's my log_customer_query view:
def chat_view(request):
    wishlist = wishlist_model.objects.filter(user=request.user) if request.user.is_authenticated else None
    sub_category = SubCategory.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]
    nav_category = Category.objects.filter(special_category=True).prefetch_related('subcategories').order_by('?')[:4]

    # Fetch the initial greeting message
    initial_response = ChatResponse.objects.get(key='greeting_message')
    response_text = initial_response.response

    # Get the options for the initial response
    options = ChatOption.objects.filter(parent_key='greeting_message')

    # Fetch all ChatResponses and store them in a dictionary with their keys
    responses = {response.key: response.response for response in ChatResponse.objects.all()}

    # Fetch all options grouped by parent_key
    options_by_parent = {}
    for option in ChatOption.objects.all():
        if option.parent_key not in options_by_parent:
            options_by_parent[option.parent_key] = []
        options_by_parent[option.parent_key].append(option)

    # Get the latest order for the user
    latest_oid = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        latest_order = CartOrder.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-order_date').first()
        if latest_order:
            latest_oid = latest_order.oid

    # Send the initial data to the template
    context = {
        'response_text': response_text,
        'options': options,
        'responses': responses,
        'options_by_parent': options_by_parent,
        'wishlist': wishlist,
        'sub_category': sub_category,
        'categories': categories,
        'nav_category': nav_category,
        'latest_oid': latest_oid,  # Pass the latest oid to the template
    }

    return render(request, 'core/chat-bot.html', context)



def log_customer_query(request):  
   user = request.user  
   query_text = request.POST.get('query_text', '')  
  
   if not user.is_authenticated:  
      return JsonResponse({'error': 'User must be authenticated to log a query.'}, status=401)  
  
   try:  
      # Fetch the latest order for the user  
      latest_order = CartOrder.objects.filter(user=user).latest('order_date')  
  
      # Create a new customer query  
      new_customer = customer.objects.create(  
        user=user,  
        title=query_text[:100],  # Limit to 100 characters  
        pid=latest_order.pid,  
        oid=latest_order.oid,  
        full_name=latest_order.full_name,  
        email=latest_order.email,  
        mobile=latest_order.mobile,  
        address=latest_order.address,  
        landmark=latest_order.landmark,  
        city=latest_order.city,  
        state=latest_order.state,  
        postalCode=latest_order.postalCode,  
        images=latest_order.images,  
        price=latest_order.price,  
        old_price=latest_order.old_price,  
        qty=latest_order.qty,  
        color=latest_order.color,  
        size=latest_order.size,  
        order_date=latest_order.order_date,  
        return_expire_date=latest_order.return_expire_date,  
        product_status=latest_order.product_status,  
      )  
      return JsonResponse({'success': 'Query logged successfully.'})  
   except CartOrder.DoesNotExist:  
      # If the user doesn't have any orders, create a new customer query without order details  
      new_customer = customer.objects.create(  
        user=user,  
        title=query_text[:100],  # Limit to 100 characters  
      )  
      return JsonResponse({'success': 'Query logged successfully.'})



def get_order_info(request):
    # Get the order ID or user ID from the request (e.g., sent by the chatbot)
    order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')
    user = request.user  # Assuming the user is logged in

    try:
        order = CartOrder.objects.get(oid=order_id, user=user)
        
        # Fetch order details
        order_data = {
            'order_id': order.oid,
            'status': order.product_status,
            'payment_status': "Paid" if order.paid_status else "Not Paid",
            'shipping_method': order.shipping_method,
            'tracking_id': order.tracking_id if order.tracking_id else "Not available",
            'tracking_website': order.tracking_website if order.tracking_website else "Not available",
            'total_price': order.price,
            'quantity': order.qty,
            'order_date': order.order_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        }
        return JsonResponse(order_data)
    except CartOrder.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Order not found.'}, status=404)

And here's my CartOrder model:
class CartOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="sku", alphabet="1234567890")
    pid = ShortUUIDField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    oid = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="oid", alphabet="1234567890")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    coupons = models.ManyToManyField("core.Coupon", blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="order-image", default="product.jpg")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
    qty = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    saved = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
    shipping_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    tracking_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    tracking_website = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stripe_payment_intent = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    return_expire_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, max_length=30, default="processing")
    return_product = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cart Order"

class customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pid = ShortUUIDField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    oid = ShortUUIDField(length=10, max_length=100, prefix="oid", alphabet="1234567890")
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    coupons = models.ManyToManyField("core.Coupon", blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to="order-image", default="product.jpg")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default="0.00")
    qty = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    return_expire_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, max_length=30, default="processing")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Customer Care"

I'm using the following JavaScript code to call the log_customer_query view:
        const chatbotResponses = {  
           welcome: "{{ response_text|escapejs }}",  // This is the welcome message  
           {% for key, response in responses.items %}  
           "{{ key }}": "{{ response|escapejs }}",  
           {% endfor %}  
        };  
          
        const chatOptions = {  
           welcome: [  
              {% for option in options %}  
              { id: {{ forloop.counter }}, text: "{{ option.text|escapejs }}", response: "{{ option.response_key|escapejs }}" },  
              {% endfor %}  
           ]  
        };  
          
        // Store options dynamically by parent_key  
        const optionsByParent = {  
           {% for parent_key, options_group in options_by_parent.items %}  
           "{{ parent_key }}": [  
              {% for option in options_group %}  
              { id: {{ forloop.counter }}, text: "{{ option.text|escapejs }}", response: "{{ option.response_key|escapejs }}" },  
              {% endfor %}  
           ],  
           {% endfor %}  
        };  
          
        // Function to add a message to the chat log  
        function addMessageToChatLog(message, type) {  
           const chatLog = document.getElementById("chat-log");  
          
           const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");  
           messageDiv.classList.add("chat-message");  
           messageDiv.classList.add(type === "user" ? "user-message" : "bot-message");  
          
           messageDiv.textContent = message;  
           chatLog.appendChild(messageDiv);  
          
           // Scroll to the bottom of the chat log  
           chatLog.scrollTop = chatLog.scrollHeight;  
        }  
          
        // Display chatbot options as buttons  
        function displayChatOptions(options) {  
           const chatOptionsContainer = document.getElementById("chat-options");  
           chatOptionsContainer.innerHTML = "";  // Clear previous options  
          
           options.forEach(option => {  
              const button = document.createElement("button");  
              button.textContent = option.text;  
              button.onclick = () => handleOptionClick(option.response, option.text);  
              chatOptionsContainer.appendChild(button);  
           });  
        }  
          
        // Handle user clicking on a chatbot option  
        function handleOptionClick(responseKey, userMessage) {  
           // Display user's message  
           addMessageToChatLog(userMessage, "user");  
          
           // Check if the responseKey relates to an order and fetch the data accordingly  
           if (responseKey === "order_status" || responseKey === "shipping_info" || responseKey === "payment_status") {  
              // Ask for the order ID to provide specific details  
              askForOrderId(responseKey);  
           } else {  
              // Get bot response based on the key  
              const botResponse = chatbotResponses[responseKey] || "Sorry, I didn’t understand that.";  
               
              // Display bot's response  
              setTimeout(() => {  
                addMessageToChatLog(botResponse, "bot");  
          
                // Check if the bot response is "Sorry, I didn’t understand that."  
                if (botResponse === "Sorry, I didn’t understand that.") {  
                   // Create a new customer query  
                   createCustomerQuery(userMessage);  
                } else {  
                   // Show new options if available  
                   if (optionsByParent[responseKey]) {  
                      displayChatOptions(optionsByParent[responseKey]);  
                   }  
                }  
              }, 500);  
           }  
        }  
          
        // Function to prompt the user to input an order ID  
        function askForOrderId(responseKey) {  
           const chatOptionsContainer = document.getElementById("chat-options");  
           chatOptionsContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options  
          
           const inputField = document.createElement("input");  
           inputField.type = "text";  
           inputField.placeholder = "Enter your Order ID";  
            
           const submitButton = document.createElement("button");  
           submitButton.textContent = "Submit";  
           submitButton.onclick = () => {  
              const orderId = inputField.value.trim();  
              if (orderId) {  
                fetchOrderDetails(orderId, responseKey);  
              } else {  
                addMessageToChatLog("Please enter a valid Order ID.", "bot");  
              }  
           };  
          
           chatOptionsContainer.appendChild(inputField);  
           chatOptionsContainer.appendChild(submitButton);  
        }  
          
        // Function to fetch order details from the backend  
        function fetchOrderDetails(orderId, responseKey) {  
           fetch(`/get_order_info/?order_id=${orderId}&type=${responseKey}`)  
              .then(response => response.json())  
              .then(data => {  
                if (data.error) {  
                   addMessageToChatLog(data.error, "bot");  
                } else {  
                   // Display relevant order information based on the response key  
                   let orderInfo = "";  
                   if (responseKey === "order_status") {  
                      orderInfo = `Order Status: ${data.status}`;  
                   } else if (responseKey === "shipping_info") {  
                      orderInfo = `Shipping Method: ${data.shipping_method}\nTracking ID: ${data.tracking_id}\nTracking Website: ${data.tracking_website}`;  
                   } else if (responseKey === "payment_status") {  
                      orderInfo = `Payment Status: ${data.payment_status}\nTotal Price: $${data.total_price}`;  
                   }  
                    
                   addMessageToChatLog(orderInfo, "bot");  
          
                   // Show new options based on the type of request  
                   if (optionsByParent[responseKey]) {  
                      displayChatOptions(optionsByParent[responseKey]);  
                   }  
                }  
              })  
              .catch(error => {  
                addMessageToChatLog("Sorry, I couldn't fetch the order details. Please try again later.", "bot");  
              });  
        }  
          
        // Function to create a new customer query  
        function createCustomerQuery(queryText) {  
           fetch('/log_customer_query/', {  
              method: 'POST',  
              headers: {  
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'  
              },  
              body: JSON.stringify({  
                query_text: queryText  
              })  
           })  
           .then(response => response.json())  
           .then(data => {  
              if (data.success) {  
                addMessageToChatLog("Your query has been logged. Our support team will get back to you soon.", "bot");  
              } else {  
                addMessageToChatLog("Sorry, we couldn't log your query. Please try again later.", "bot");  
              }  
           })  
           .catch(error => {  
              addMessageToChatLog("Sorry, we couldn't log your query. Please try again later.", "bot");  
           });  
        }  
          
        // Function to send a message to the chatbot  
        function sendMessage() {  
           const userInput = document.getElementById("user-input").value.trim();  
           if (userInput) {  
              addMessageToChatLog(userInput, "user");  
              const responseKey = getResponseKey(userInput);  
              handleOptionClick(responseKey, userInput);  
              document.getElementById("user-input").value = "";  
           }  
        }  
          
        // Function to get the response key based on the user's input  
        function getResponseKey(userInput) {  
           // This function should return the response key based on the user's input  
           // For now, it just returns a default response key  
           return "default_response";  
        }  
          
        // Display welcome message and options on page load  
        window.onload = function () {  
           addMessageToChatLog(chatbotResponses.welcome, "bot");  // Show the welcome message  
           displayChatOptions(chatOptions.welcome);  // Show the initial options  
        };


Error:
The problem is that the log_customer_query view is not returning the phone number from the CartOrder model. I've tried printing out the latest_order object and the mobile field, but they're both empty.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the log_customer_query view to return the phone number of the user's latest order.
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a new CartOrder object with a valid phone number.
Call the log_customer_query view using the JavaScript code above.
Check the response from the view to see if it returns the phone number.


Do you mean that the saved customer object has a null value or empty string for the mobile attribute? That's entirely possible given your CartOrder.mobile field has null and blank set to true. If you on the other hand are expecting the response from the request to contain the phone number, why do you expect that? None of your response objects contain that in it.

Thanks for the response! The CartOrder.mobile field does allow null and blank, but I’ve verified that valid phone numbers are saved in the database for some orders. However, when I query the latest order using:
latest_order = CartOrder.objects.filter(user=user).latest('order_date')

The mobile field in the returned object is empty or None, even though the database record has a valid value. My JSON response is:
return JsonResponse({'phone_number': latest_order.mobile})


Are you sure the latest order has a value for the mobile field stored in the database? Also no, the code you show doesn't have JsonResponse({'phone_number': latest_order.mobile}) anywhere...

Yes, I’ve double-checked the database, and the mobile field does have a value for the latest order. Apologies for the confusion regarding the code snippet—I meant that the JsonResponse in my actual implementation references latest_order.mobile. Could there be an issue with how the latest_order query retrieves data, or should I debug further to confirm if the value is being overwritten elsewhere?

"I meant that the JsonResponse in my actual implementation references latest_order.mobile" give us a proper [mre], how do you expect us to answer a question about some code you don't even share with us?

I edited my question and provided all the code please check it out

I have provided all the code related to it. Please now help me out!!!
